# How to detect if slide menu is opened or closed using SlideHolder in android

Tags: android, android-sliding

I am using the slideHolder class for using slide menu in my project. I want to get notified in my fragment, when slide is opened or closed. I have tried the following line of code also:

```
SlideHolder.setOnSlideListener(SlideHolder.OnSlideListener);
```

But its giving error. How to detect the open and close event of the slide menu?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are doing it correctly, can you tell what error you are getting and does the same error occur without `setOnSlideListener(listiner)`

Comment: Its giving me the following error when calling it in OnCreateView:
1) create constant OnSlideLIstener in type SlideHolder
2) create field OnSlideLIstener in type SlideHolder

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use a code similar to this. You need to implement your SlideHolderListener.

```
    sliderMenu.setOnSlideListener(new SlideHolder.OnSlideListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSlideCompleted(boolean opened) {
                if(opened)
                    // do whatever need once menu opened
                else
                    // do whatever need once menu closed
            }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I am placing this code in onCreate method of my fragment, my app is crashing. Where should i call setOnSlideListener event in my code??

Comment: Also I have one more doubt, How are you initializing the sliderMenu object?